# Is GC a thread in .net

Tags: .net

> Garbage Collection is a daemon thread in java.
>   I have a great confusion, Is Garbage Collection also a thread in Dot net ??

Comment: It depends on your computer and .NET version, etc.

Comment: I am using .net 4.0 and my system configuration (RAM-4.0 GB , System Type-64 bit O.S., Processor- Intel(R) core(TM)-i5.....

Comment: The number of occasions when you will need to know any of this is vanishingly small. What is the scenario you think this matters for? chances are good that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The garbage collector isn't "a thread" in either .NET or Java. On both platforms another thread is (or possibly multiple threads are) *used* by the garbage collector - to run finalizers on, for example. The actual garbage collection *could* be executed on separate threads, too. But that doesn't mean that the garbage collector *is* a daemon thread, any more than a web server is a thread.

(If you were just wanting to know whether the garbage collector in .NET required at least one thread in addition to any threads that your application creates, the answer is yes... but you need to be clear in your mind about what exactly you're interested in.)

Comment: If GC need at least one thread..  .net have any default thread that help to GC??

Comment: @PrinceeSinghal: What do you mean by "default thread"? As far as I'm aware, the finalizer thread is just created on start-up. (I can't remember offhand whether .NET ever uses multiple finalizer threads, but it logically could.)

Comment: @PrinceeSinghal: Um, finalization is part of garbage collection... so yes, the GC uses the finalizer thread - nothing else could! That doesn't mean that *all* of the GC activity occurs on the finalizer thread though. Different GC implementations work differently. Some use multiple threads, others don't. Sometimes most of the work will be done on the user thread (the one waiting for memory), sometimes not. None of this should usually affect the code you write.